# Does this chart closely resemble a classic dead cat bounce?

Tags: stocks, trading, technical-analysis, trend-trading

There is a picture of a chart that looks like a dead cat bounce:

[image]

I saw this in an undisclosed source. I have also read about what a dead cat bounce is. This chart resembles dead cat bounce closely. I just wonder if this resembles a textbook dead-cat bounce. If it does, how strong is the resemblance?

Answer (score 2):

A Dead Cat Bounce is a short recovery following a long decline, typically followed by another long decline. So without a longer history to see if there was a long decline before, there's no way to know if this resembles that indicator.

Even then, it doesn't necessarily mean that the stock will continue to fall - the stock could have met some resistance and may continue to stay at that level, or it may go up. There is absolutely no way to know what direction it will go from here.